# Usage of DARE as an auxiliary verb

Tags: modal-verbs

1)What is the meaning of this sentence??

> **Dared** he say so??

2)As **dared** is past, shouldn't we use **said** instead of **say** in the sentence??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Dared" here is a semi-modal verb so it will mark the past tense of the verb ***to say*** the way an auxiliary does. It will also mark the Subject-Verb inversion in the interrogation. Consider:

> Affirmative question
>
> - Does anyone dare (to) go there? (ordinary verb)
> - Dare anyone go there? (semi-modal verb) ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/dare))

If you put these two questions in the past you get:

> - Did anyone dare (to) go there? (ordinary verb)
> - Dared anyone go there? (semi-modal verb)

Note that in questions, "dare" is more often used with "how":

> [How dared he say that?](https://www.englishpage.net/showthread.php?12402-semi-modal)

For example:

> ***How dared he say*** that he would love her still, even though she shook him off with contempt? ([*NORTH AND SOUTH*](http://www.victorianlondon.org/etexts/gaskell/north_and_south-0025.shtml), by Elizabeth Gaskell)